# How to handle question marks in mv command?

Tags: bash, mv

I have the following script to get rid of characters that a FAT32 system wouldn't like:

```
bad_chars="\?:\|\"*"
F=`find . | grep [$bad_chars] | head -n1`
while [ "$F" != "" ]
do
    new_F=`echo $F` | sed s/[$bad_chars]/_/g`
    mv "$F" "$new_F"
    F=`find . | grep [$bad_chars] | head -n1`
done
```

Now it's getting stuck on files with question marks, it comes up with the error

```
mv: rename ./[FILE_PATH]/What? _.pdf to ./[FILE_PATH]/What_ _.pdf: No such file or directory.
```

It does not do this to all files with question marks, I tried adding a dummy `?.txt` file and it handled it fine. There are other pdfs in the same path but they are not similar in name.

Comment: If you have the rename utility you could reduce it to just a `find exec/xargs rename`. Also the way you are doing this will break for filenames with newlines in them. And the question marks are most likely not question marks but other bad characters that you cannot see.

Comment: I know this one is not a bad char because the `sed` changes it and I've found strange unicode characters that I've put into bad_chars and it draws them just fine. Unfortunately I don't have the rename util (helping out someone else on their mac)

Comment: Sed will change it because you just pass it a string with a question mark in it, not the actual filename.

Comment: Why are you using sed when Bash can substitute like `mv "$F" "${F//[$bad_chars]/_}"`?  And why grep when Find can do the job: `find . -name "*[$bad_chars]*" -ls`?  Are you sure that you're seeing a literal `?` in its output?  If you're using GNU find, prefer the use of `-print0` -- see the section entitled ***Unusual Filenames*** in the manual.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be useful to show us some examples of file names.

Comment: I'm a C++ programmer and barely touch bash day to day so I'm kind of in the dark. I'm just going to do the ones my terrible script can't get by hand. I'll delete this in a bit.

Comment: @Cramer: No, don't delete this. We answer to help future visitors, too (though it's fathomable that this would be too specific to help many future visitors).

Answer (score 1):

I think that the script can be simplified quite a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar  # enable recursive expansion with **
shopt -s nullglob  # expand to nothing if no files match the pattern

bad_chars="\?:\|\"*"
for i in **/*["$bad_chars"]*; do 
    mv "$i" "${i//[$bad_chars]/}"
done
```

Comment: Judging by OP's comments that it works when they make a file with `?`, then this would likely have the same problems as OP's.

Comment: Totally works for me with or without files containing `?` - not really sure what the problem was there but the OP's code seems a bit broken anyway as there's an odd number of backticks on the line assigning to `new_F`.

Comment: My point is that it won't work with weird characters which is probably what OP is dealing with as they already said it works when they make a file with `?` in it. Also might want to mention that globstar only works in bash 4+

Comment: If the user has other characters that simply are displayed as `?`, that's another problem altogether. This is a vast improvement over running `find` repeatedly, only to use one of the files it returns each time.